# Using Date to Filter Entries

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

I am trying to pull entries that match a date criteria. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
section: 'leads',
lastAssigned: '("now"|date_modify("-3 days"))'
}) %}
```

I get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in .../craft/app/helpers/DbHelper.php on line 597
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the quotes that is throwing it off. Try this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
section: 'leads',
lastAssigned: now | date_modify("-3 days")
}) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jameal put me on the right track here. What I actually needed was to select entries where lastAssigned date was more than 3 days old. I accomplished this by.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'leads',
    lastAssigned:' <' ~ now |date_modify("-3 days")
}) %}
```

Posting my solution here because I think this will be helpful to someone in the future.